# Apache https redirection results in 400 error

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, http-status-code-404, tomcat6, mod-ssl

This issue is happening on a Red Hat instance. The apache installed is version [Apache/2.2.19] and the mod_ssl version is [2.2.16.]
HTTP access works fine, but when mod_rewrite is enabled for http to https redirection, it results in following 400 Error:

```
Bad Request

Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.
Request header field is missing ':' separator.
```

The error in Apache's error_log file is:

```
request failed: error reading the headers
```

The similar setup is working in another environment. Can someone please help me to resolve this.

Thanks
Noman A.

Comment: +1 Good to know you resolved the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found solution for this.

It appears that the reboot of the system updated my yum packages, including **httpd** [2.2.22] which was conflicting with my Apache installation [2.2.19].

I updated the **mod_ssl.so** [2.2.16] in my Apache to **mod_ssl.so** [2.2.22] and the error was resolved.

Comment: How did you update it? In which directory is this file?

Comment: Yeah, how did you update it exactly?  How do I know to check for the version of ssl that might be causing this by looking at my php info file?  Thx

Answer (score 1):

Updating mod_ssl and httpd fixed this issue for us too. Thanks to all who contributed.